# Meta Tags for FB share - do I need to use regular meta tags as well? what type to use for an html5 game?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a FB share link in a game I just published on a website, and don't really know the rules for meta tags on an html page. I have the og tags set up from looking at this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

Questions:

- Do i also need regular meta tags - like description, keywords, etc?
  Or if I use the fb tags, is that all that's needed?
- Do meta tags take
  a while to kick in? I set the og tags, and the FB share window still
  shows old info
- I have the type set up as "website" - is that the og
  type I should use for an HTML5 game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, you should also provide regular metatags
- Refresh the tags in the debugger if the are not correct: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
- There is no specific game tag, so "website" should be alright: http://ogp.me/